# Limits of tmpfs filesystem

Tags: filesystems, limit, tmpfs

What are the limits of the tmpfs filesystem in terms of:

- Maximum file size
- Maximum file system size
- Maximum subdirectories
- Maximum symlink depth

I'm using a centOS 8. The tmpfs is mounted via:

```
[root@sst ~]# cat /etc/fstab
[...]
tmpfs                   /mnt/mytmpfs            tmpfs   defaults,nr_inodes=1k,size=30%  0 0
```

I can't find any useful information about this topic.

Comment: At least some of these things would depend on the mount options used.  For `tmpfs`, these are described in the `mount(8)` manual (`man 8 mount`).

Comment: I've added more details. At the moment i have no problem. It's more a theoretical question. Because i could not find any information searching for file system limits for tmpfs.

Comment: Well, you can create directories until you run out of inodes, and you have allocated 1k inodes. You have specified that the filesystem size is 30% of RAM.  The only thing left is the symlink depth.

Comment: @Kusalananda The official `tmpfs` documentation is in the `tmps(7fs)` manual and in the `mount_tmpfs(1m)` man page. The original question did not mention that the OP is interested in the Linux clone implementation instead of the SunOS original.

Comment: @schily The original did not, but the current question does.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since you mentioned you are running CentOS, I am answering regarding the Linux implementation of tmpfs. I am writing this clarification to respond to comments which mention that the [SunOS implementation of tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#SunOS) (which seems to be the original implementation) or implementations in other *nix-like OSes may be different.

From the [Linux kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

> tmpfs has three mount options for sizing:
>
> - `size`:      The limit of allocated bytes for this tmpfs instance. The 
>            default is half of your physical RAM without swap. If you
>            oversize your tmpfs instances the machine will deadlock
>            since the OOM handler will not be able to free that memory.
> - `nr_blocks`: The same as size, but in blocks of PAGE_SIZE.
> - `nr_inodes`: The maximum number of inodes for this instance. The default
>            is half of the number of your physical RAM pages, or (on a
>            machine with highmem) the number of lowmem RAM pages,
>            whichever is the lower.

So, when you specify `inodes=1k`, you are limiting the number of files to 1,000. 
When you specify `size=30%`, you are limiting the total filesystem size to 30% of your RAM.

Otherwise, I see no limits imposed, and, as written in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html):

> - The filesystem can employ swap space when physical memory pressure
>           demands it.
> - The filesystem consumes only as much physical memory and swap
>           space as is required to store the current contents of the filesys‐
>           tem.

The symlink resolution depth is mandated by the OS, not the filesystem, according to the [path_resolution man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html):

> As currently implemented on Linux, the maximum number of symbolic
>          links that will be followed while resolving a pathname is 40.

Comment: This may be true for the `tmpfs` clone found on Linux, but it does not apply to the original implementation that  first appeared on SunOS in 1988.

Comment: @schily This seems like a rather irrelevant observation seeing that the user is not running SunOS, Solaris or a Unix derived thereof.

Comment: @Kusalananda When I read the question, it did not mention theOS and it may of course be important that the limitations are Linux specific as the SunOS original introuces (unlike the Linux clone) no artificial limits. SunOS is self configuring at runtime and (unless the size has been limited via mount option) offers as much space as could be offered without eating up all memory or swap space. This make tmpfs easier to use than the lnux clone.

Comment: @schily Since the question mentions CentOS, is see no reason to consider the SunOS implementation, unless it runs on Linux (in which case you should probably mention that in an answer).

Comment: @Kusalananda as mentioned already, I did not mention the original if the OP did include a hint to Linx from the beginning already.

Comment: @schily I am interested - if this does not apply to SunOS, what does apply to the SunOS implementation of tmpfs? I cannot tell the difference between what you wrote, "SunOS introduces not artificial limits", between what I wrote, "I see no limits imposed" -- other than those specified when the user creates the mount (e.g. by specifying `inodes` or `size` in `fstab`)?